# What steps are necessary to apply an Enterprise license to an iDRAC7 that shipped with a different license?

Tags: dell, licensing, drac

I have an iDRAC7 that came with an Express License.  I have purchased an Enterprise license. What do I need to do to activate the license on my iDRAC7?

Comment: Licensing questions are off-topic at SF.

Comment: Mostly, I though it was useful to document the technical process of applying the license, since I had to comb through several different sets of documentation to get the full process.  Is there better wording I could use to emphasize that this about the mechanism of applying a license you already have?

Comment: I'd contact your Dell representative directly as they would be the ones to know about this.

Comment: Okay, I've edited the question to focus specifically on the technical steps required to apply an already-purchased license.  This is not about choosing or purchasing a license and the question is applicable to many different environments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to go through the DRAC's web interface to apply it.  (I've tried using `radacm` from a Linux install on the system--`racadm license import -f <filename>` *should* work--but I keep getting told that my iDRAC doesn't support `racadm` commands.)

From the BIOS, press F2 to enter System Setup and go to "iDRAC Settings".  Configure its network and its user account.  Exit the system setup, saving your changes as prompted, and let the system reboot.  Once the DRAC is accessible on the network, visit it with a web browser, log in, and go to the Overview > Server > Licenses page.  On the "iDRAC" line, under the "License Options" drop-down menu, click "Import".  Select the license XML file you obtained earlier and click "Apply".

At this point you should reboot your system once more, as the documentation indicates that some features may not be available until the system has been fully power cycled.

Answer (score 3):

First I test the racadm account locally:

> racadm getsysinfo

And if that works drop the XML file on that systems desktop and do the following:

> racadm license import -f "C:\somepath\lic.xml" -c idrac.embedded.1

You should see the license type output afterwards.